# Chebyshev's Inequality in proof of Proposition 23 of Royden?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, lebesgue-integral

This is from the 4th edition of Royden, on page 92.

> **Proposition 23.** Let $f$ be a measurable function on $E$.
>   If $f$ is integrable over $E$, then for each $\epsilon >0$,
>   there is a $\delta >0$ for which 
>   $$\text{if } A\subset E \text{ is measurable and } m(A) < \delta, \text{ then } \int_A |f| < \epsilon. \tag{*}$$

Royden's proof:

We assume that $f \geq 0$ on $E$ and that $f$ is integrable over $E$.
Then by additivity over domains of integration and Chebyshev's Inequality,
if $A\subset E$ is measurable and $c > 0$,
then
$$ \int_A f = \int_{\{x\in A\, \mid\, f(x) < c\} } f
           + \int_{\{x\in A\, \mid\, f(x) \geq c\} } f
\leq c \cdot m(A) + \frac{1}{c} \int_E f. \tag{1}$$

Choose $c >0$ such that $1/c \cdot \int_E f < \epsilon /2$.
Then $$\int_A f < c \cdot m(A) + \epsilon /2. $$
Define $\delta = \epsilon / 2c$. Then (*) holds for this choice of $\delta$.

---

I'm having trouble working out this last inequality.
So I have
$$\int_{\{x\in A\, \mid\, f(x) < c\} } f
= \int_A f \cdot \chi_{\{x\in A\, \mid\, f(x) < c\} } < \int_A c = c \cdot m(A),$$
which takes care of the first part,
but I can't see how to use Chebyshev's Inequality to get
$$\int_{\{x\in A\, \mid\, f(x) \geq c\} } f \leq \frac{1}{c} \int_E f,$$
since Chebyshev's inequality would give us
$$\int_A \chi_{\{x\in A: f(x) \geq c\}} = m\{x\in A: f(x) \geq c\} \leq \frac{1}{c} \int_A f $$
but we have a non-constant integrand $f$? 
How do we use Chebyshev's Inequality to get (1)?

Comment: \frac{1}{c} \int_A f \le \frac{1}{c} \int_E f (because A subset of E)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Chebyshev's Inequality here. The proof is as follow:

Let $B_n=\{x:x\in E,\:n-1<f(x)\leqslant n\}$ and $C=\{x:x\in E,\:f(x)>n\}$. 
We have
$$
\int_Efdm=\int_{\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n}fdm=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{B_n}fdm
$$
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{B_n}fdm$ is absolute convergent, given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $N$ such that for any $n>N$
$$
\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\int_{B_n}fdm=\int_{\bigcup_{n=N+1}^{\infty}B_n}fdm<\epsilon/2\tag{1}
$$
Let 
$$
B=\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}B_n\quad\text{and}\quad C=\bigcup_{n=N+1}^{\infty}B_n=E-B
$$
Take $\delta=\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(N+1)}$. Then for any $A\subset E$ such that $m(A)<\delta$, by $(1)$
$$
\int_Afdm=\int_{A\cap (B\cup C)}fdm=\int_{A\cap B}fdm+\int_{A\cap C}fdm\leqslant N\int_Adm+\int_Cfdm<N\dfrac{\epsilon}{2(N+1)}+\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon
$$

Comment: Thank you! This is super clean/clear. Also, would you happen to know how the proof using Royden's approach would go? I'm dying to know how that inequality works (chebyshev); I feel like it's something incredibly simple that I'm just overlooking..

Comment: Ohh, I meant I want to understand how Royden is using Chebyshev's in his proof. I edited the question with the full proof. It seems like something I should know? But I like the proofs given here, so maybe I should just move on..

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question

Comment: OP is pleased with the answer. The fact is that there is no need for Chebyshev here. Why downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is via the Dominated Convergnce Theorem: $\lim_{c\to \infty} \int_{\{x\in A: f(x)\ge c\}} f(x)\,dx=\lim_{c\to \infty}\int_E 1_{\{f\ge c\}\cap A}f\,dx=0$ because the integrand $1_{\{f\ge c\}\cap A}f$ converges to $0$ a.e. and is dominated on $E$ by the integrable function $f$.

Comment: Why does  $1_{\{f\ge c\}\cap A}f \rightarrow 0$ a.e. as $c \rightarrow 0^+$?
I thought it would be
$1_{\{f\ge c\}\cap A}f \rightarrow 1_{A} f$ since $f \geq 0$ on $E$?

Comment: Corrected now; I wanted the large $c$ limit.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having trouble working out this last inequality.

I will show this inequality is not valid.

> $\int_A f =
> \int_{ \{x \in A | f(x)<c \} } f + \int_{ \{ x \in A | f(x) \ge c \} } f \le
> c \cdot m(A) + \dfrac{1}{c} \int_E f$.

Let $c > 1$ and $a > \dfrac{c^2}{c-1}$. Then $a > c + \dfrac{1}{c}a$.

Define $f : [0,1] \to [ 0, \infty)$ by $f(x) = a$.
$\:$ Let $E = A = [0,1]$.

$\int_A f = \int_0^1 a \chi_{ A } = a$. $\:$
$\int_E f = \int_0^1 a \chi_{ E } = a$.

$c \cdot m(A) + \dfrac{1}{c} \int_E f =
c \cdot 1 + \dfrac{1}{c} a$.

Therefore,  $\int_A f = a > c + \dfrac{1}{c}a
= c \cdot m(A) + \dfrac{1}{c} \int_E f$.

---

> I can't see how to use Chebyshev's Inequality to get ...

Using the same example, I will show this inequality is not valid.

> $\int_{ \{ x \in A | f(x) \ge c \} } f \le \dfrac{1}{c} \int_E f$.

Since $c > 1$, $\dfrac{c^2}{c-1} > c$. $\:$
Since $a > \dfrac{c^2}{c-1}$, $a > c$. $\:$
Since $f(x)=a$, $f(x) > c$.

Therefore, $\{ x \in A | f(x) \ge c \} = A$. $\:$
$\int_{ \{ x \in A | f(x) \ge c \} } f = \int_A f$.

Since $c > 1$, $\dfrac{a}{c} < a$.

Therefore, $\int_{ \{ x \in A | f(x) \ge c \} } f = \int_A f = a > \dfrac{a}{c} = \dfrac{1}{c} \int_E f$.

---

My conclusion is Chebychev's inequality will not help.